# How to get only folder size from "du"?

Tags: bash

I need to get the size of my folder, for comparison. But I get the folder size with the path. How to get only the size of my folder? I use the following command in `bash`:

```
size=`du -b --max-depth=0  ./main_folder/data`
```

Output:

```
12260550 ./main_folder/data
```

Expected:

```
12260550
```

Comment: Use `du -b --max-depth=0  ./main_folder/data | cut -f1`

Answer (score 3):

`cut` is a dedicated command for that type of manipulation on strings.

```
size=`du -b --max-depth=0  ./main_folder/data | cut -f1`
```

Here `-f1` means "cut the first field" (on each line of piped input, but there is only one line).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're trying to store size in a variable, you can just take first value and ignore rest as:

```
read size _ < <(du -b --max-depth=0 main_folder/data)

echo "size=$size"
```

Comment: Note: the `_` absorbs the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The most sensical answer to me is the following

```
du -b --max-depth=0  ./main_folder/data | awk '{print $1;}'
```

Returns first word of output. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
du -sh ./main_folder/data | awk '{print $1;}'

s -> summarizes all the contents of the folder

h -> return output in human readable form
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this one liner:

```
myvar=$(du -b --max-depth=0 ./main_folder/data|cut -f1 -d$'\t')
```